# formulate excel to minimise levels of nesting

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to use the formula as below and it is showing an error however I do not want to nest each item individually because the text data/variables I need to use is so immense that if I compiled a nesting for each item then it is exceeding the maximum 64 levels of nesting excel allows, by grouping together my data will be able to keep under 64 levels of nesting.

=IF(AND(B1="Apple" OR "Kiwi" OR "Orange"), "Fruits", IF(AND(B1="Carrots" OR "Tomato" OR "Celery"), "Vegetables",""))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a secondary table:

[image]

Then use VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,E:F,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

---

If you really want to hard code the choices then use OR with an array:

```
=IF(OR(A2={"Apple","Kiwi","Orange"}),"Fruits",IF(OR(A2={"Carrots","Tomato","Celery"}),"Vegetables",""))
```

[image]

Comment: the hard code option worked much better, cheers Scott